# How can I find associations that DON'T exist with Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I want to represent this in Rails / ActiveRecord using associations:

```
SELECT
  locations.* 
FROM
  locations
  LEFT JOIN items_locations ON locations.id = items_locations.location_id
  AND items_locations.item_id = 166
WHERE
  items_locations.item_id IS NULL
```

Currently I have

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :locations
end
```

This pulls in all locations associated with an item via a simple mapper table called items_locations. My goal is to change this to pull in all location records NOT associated with the item.

What should the association look like in my model to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want all locations whose item_id is not 166. You didn't specify what version of Rails you are using, but in Rails 3 the query would look like this if the item_id is a variable:

```
Location.where("item_id != ?", my_item_id)
```

This will get all locations whose item_id is not equal to my_item_id.

Comment: Almost but not quite. I need this in the FROM clause's LEFT JOIN: "AND items_locations.item_id = 166". Otherwise no records will be returned.